# Windows 7 x64 Slow Hibernation

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hibernate

Why does it take so long for Windows 7 x64 to enter and leave hibernation?

On my laptop, Windows 7 x64 takes ~40 seconds to hibernate, whereas Windows XP x64 takes ~4-6 seconds. Furthermore, leaving hibernation is around ~15-20 seconds for Windows 7 x64, whereas it's about ~3-4 seconds for Windows XP.

**Every** hardware aspect is the same in both situations. (The amount of addressable memory, the hibernation file size, etc.)

What's the deal?

---

Update: My own guess is that the SATA controller driver is slow, but I have no way to verify this... the disk works fine at other times. :\

My laptop is: Sony VAIO VPCCW27FX

- CPU: Core i5 520M (2.4 - 2.9 GHz)
- RAM: 4GB DDR3, 532MHz (*I've already played around with the `/MaxMem` boot flag, it doesn't affect anything.*)
- Hard disk: 5400 RPM SATA, UDMA 6 (150 MB/s)

I've tried installing a different SATA controller driver (changed `Standard` to `Intel`), but no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without specifics on the machine and what's running, but more than likely there's either A: A particular process running or B: A device driver that doesn't play as well with hibernation in 7 as it does in XP.  It's also possible you simply have more utilization under 7 period which is exacerbating the problem.

EDIT: I'm assuming that everything works normally in both, it's just slower in 7.  There's nothing inherently slower about the process under 7 so it must be something else.

Comment: @Shinrai: I'm not sure what you mean by "more utilization under 7 period"... utilization of what? And why does it even affect hibernation, given that everything is paused?

Comment: @Mehrdad - I mean you have more background processes and stuff running.  The more that has to be stopped and written to the hiberfile, the longer it takes?  (This would also manifest in slightly longer shutdowns for that matter.)

Comment: @Mehrdad - And let me add that I agree with you that a SATA controller driver could totally cause this (but again, not knowing the hardware I can't say for sure).

Comment: @Shinrai: Actually, my computer is *very* clean -- there's barely anything running on it, and there's **no** background process that's using the hard disk or the CPU; I'm very frantic about keeping it clean. Furthermore, the shutdowns are actually just as fast as XP's (as are the startups) -- it's just the boot that's different. (I'll put my laptop's specs in my post, if that helps.)

Comment: @Mehrdad - In that case, I'll stand by my original assertion (and your suspicion) that there's a device driver to blame.  You'll probably just have to live with it.